# Does this infinite primes snake-product converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Form an infinite product of prime ratios as follows.
Start with
$$
\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{7}{5}=\frac{14}{15} \approx 0.93 \;.
$$
Continue alternating a fraction $< 1$ times the next fraction $>1$,
progressively through the primes:
$$
\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{7}{5}\cdot\frac{11}{13}\cdot\frac{19}{17}
= \frac{2926}{3315} \approx 0.88 \;,
$$
$$
\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{7}{5}\cdot\frac{11}{13}\cdot\frac{19}{17}\cdot\frac{23}{29}\cdot\frac{37}{31}
=\frac{2490026}{2980185} \approx 0.83 \;.
$$
Continue this process to $\infty$. One way to write the product is
$$
\xi = \prod_{1,5,9,\ldots}^\infty 
\frac{p_i}{p_{i+1}}\cdot\frac{p_{i+3}}{p_{i+2}}
$$
where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime.
I call this the *primes snake-product*:

---

[image: Snake]

---

My questions are:

> ***Q1***. Does the product converge?
>
> ***Q2***. If so, to what value $\xi$ does it converge?

Up to the $1$-millionth prime ($15485863$),
the product is about $0.9056$:

---

[image: Prod_1M]

---

**Update** (*26Jan2019*): @Peter has calculated out to $p_i=10^{10}$ when the product is
$\approx 0.9048$.

Comment: Using the prime number theorem as an approximation, if you set $p_n=n\ln(n)$, does your product converge?

Comment: $10^6$ th prime : $$0.90556367385\cdots $$ $10^7$ th prime : $$0.90502381939\cdots $$

Comment: $10^8$ th prime : $$0.90482881546\cdots $$

Comment: You could prove that the value of $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{p_{2n-1}}{p_{2n}} = P$ converges. Then, you can easily see that $P < \xi < \frac{1}{P}$, which would show that your product converges.

Comment: @Haran: But perhaps $P=0$, and I'd be left with $0 < \xi < \infty$.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for those calculations. The product is steadily decreasing, but apparently at a diminishing rate.

Comment: If there is any justice in this world then that has to converge. But actually proving that it actually does seems hard. Let's say the primes have a really "stoopid" distribution though: Every time $p_{n+1}$ is significantly larger than $p_n$, the integer $n$ is odd. So I am not sure that the PNT is strong enough

Comment: @quarague That is a fairly poor approximation since the cross-ratio is essentially taking a derivative and PNT says very little about differences in spacing between primes.  However it does convince in one direction: if the smooth approximation fails to converge then it is rather hopeless for the real one to converge.

Comment: (In fact this product acts more like a second derivative and so the smooth approximation is very weak indeed!)

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I meant to say that we have to prove $P>0$

Comment: Not sure if presicion is an issue, but my calculations say that the value goes up again at around $7*10^9$. https://imgur.com/a/4f4iZW2

Comment: $$64000000, 5470966339, 5470966349, 5470966351, 5470966379, 0.9048566195664\cdots$$ hence at this stage the product virtually stagnates. I "only" used about 30-digit-precision, so I cannot guarantee that the calculation is absolutely stable, but I do not think this is a big issue. I will continue, but my PARI/GP version is not the fastest program, when primes upto $10^{10}$ have to be generated. Maybe, modern programs have much more pre-calculated primes.

Comment: @Haran $P=0$, because $p_{2n}/p_{2n+1}<1-1/p_{2n+1}$ and $p_{2n+1}\sim 2n\log n$. Since series $\sum 1/n\log n$ diverges, this product tends to $0$.

Comment: Very interesting question! What about another snake-products? For example we have $\sqrt{2}-1$ for odd.

Comment: Since (as I note above) the products of $\frac{p_i}{p_{i+1}}$ and of $\frac{p_{i+3}}{p_{i+2}}$ do not converge absolutely, we are lead to considering cancelations between the terms. This is closely related to asymptotics of alternating sums of primes, of which we have only a limited understanding. See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164936/is-the-alternating-sum-of-primes-2-3-5-p-n-asymptotic-to-n-ln-n-2?noredirect=1&lq=1). I will elaborate in an answer.

Comment: I finished the calculation upto the primes until $10^{10}$. The final product is $$0.904831220025147\cdots $$ slightly larger than the value after the $10^8$ th prime.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I did not arrive at $i=10^{10}$, I only arrived at $10^{10}$ (not the $10^{10}$ th prime)

Comment: The last quartuple I considered is $$[9999999929, 9999999943, 9999999967, 10000000019]$$ which is the $$113\ 763\ 128$$ th quartuple.

Comment: If anyone can see that $\xi \approx 0.9048$ can be seen in relation to other fundamental constants, let us know, even conjecturally. Naively, it is close to $19/21$.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322491/does-this-infinite-primes-snake-product-converge

Answer (score 17):

A very extended comment explaining why this problem is probably difficult.

Let $g_n=p_{2n}-p_{2n-1}$. The product we are looking at is then
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{g_n}{p_{2n}}\right)^{(-1)^n}.$$
Taking logarithms, we are met with a sum of the form
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left((-1)^{n-1}\frac{g_n}{p_{2n}}+O\left(\left(\frac{g_n}{p_{2n}}\right)^2\right)\right).$$
Using results due to Heath-Brown on second moments on prime gaps (see [here](https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s2-19/2/207/818223?redirectedFrom=PDF)), namely $\sum_{k=1}^ng_k^2=O(x^{7/6+\varepsilon})$, by summation by parts we can bound the sum of the error terms by a finite value.

Hence we are left with an alternating sum of $g_n/p_{2n}$. To deal with this, we essentially have to show the sums $\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^{n-1}g_n$ are asymptotically smaller than $p_{2N}$ (this won't guarantee convergence, but we definitely want that to hold). Using the notation of [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/164936/30186) (and the paper it cites), this sum is equal to $S(2N;1,4)-S(2N;3,4)$. What we would like to know is that this difference is $o(p_{2N})$. So you see we are quickly lead to investigating asymptotics of $S(N;a,q)$. Conjecturally, we have
$$S(N;a,q)\sim\frac{p_N}{q}$$
(so that the gaps are in some sense equidistributed), but available bounds are much weaker. In the cases we are interested in, we only get
$$\liminf\frac{S(N;a,4)}{p_N}\geq\frac{1}{256}$$
unconditionally, and even conditionally on prime tuples conjecture we get $\geq 1/32$, while what we would like is for the limits to exist and be equal.

Hence, as you can see, the available methods are not capable of showing that the difference $S(2N;1,4)-S(2N;3,4)$ is asymptotically small.

Comment: Thank you for your knowledgeable remarks. May I ask: Do you know if there a well-known conjecture that would imply the snake-product converges?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Not really, no. It should follow from suitable error term estimates for $S(N;a,q)$, but I'm not aware of such conjectures. I haven't exactly checked the references in the linked answer, you might want to look there.

Comment: One of the [strongest conjecture](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/254a-supplement-4-probabilistic-models-and-heuristics-for-the-primes-optional/#cram) for the prime gap is that $g(n),n \in [N,2N]$ looks like a random variable $G_N$ with $P(G_N > a\log N) = e^{-a} \log N$ and you are essentially asking $g(n)$ to be at least slightly independent in $n$ @JosephO'Rourke