# When does a sequence's snake-product converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Following this earlier unanswered question,
[Does this infinite primes snake-product converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3087001/237)

([MO version](https://mathoverflow.net/q/322491/6094)),
I would like to pose a more general question.
Given any increasing sequence $s_i$ of natural numbers,
form the infinite *snake-product* by multiplying fractions
$\frac{s_i}{s_{i+1}} \cdot \frac{s_{i+3}}{s_{i+2}}$.
For example, if the sequence $s$ is just the natural numbers, $1,2,3, \ldots$, the snake-product $\sigma( s )$ is:

$$
\sigma = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{8}{7}\cdot\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{12}{11} \cdot \cdots 
 \approx 0.59907 \;.
$$

The approximate product shown is what I computed up to $i=10^6$.
A specific question:

> ***Q1***. Does the above product (for the sequence  $s_i = i$) converge, and if so, to what number?

*Answered* by @Peter: Yes, converges to
$$
\frac{ \sqrt{2} \, \pi^{3/2} } { \Gamma( \frac{1}{4} )^2 } 
\approx 0.59907 \;.
$$

I would be interested to see other example sequences that appear to, or can be proved to, converge. One might distinguish between strictly increasing sequences and non-decreasing sequences.

And the more general title question:

> ***Q2***. Under what conditions on the sequence $s_i$ will
>   the snake-product converge?

Comment: Since pretty much any infinite product can be approximated by such a sequence, Q2 is not going to have a general answer. But you can at least consider conditions when the product (of pairs of terms) is absolutely convergent, and by the usual methods this is equivalent to the series
$$\sum \left| \frac{s_{4i+1} s_{4i+4}}{s_{4i+2} s_{4i+3}} - 1 \right|$$
is absolutely convergent. Or, taking logarithms and thinking about the alternatiging series test, it converges whenever $s_{i}/s_{i-1}$ is an (eventually) decreasing sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the exact limit :

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+(sqrt(%CF%80)+%CE%93(7%2F4)+%CE%93(5%2F4+%2B+k)+%CE%93(2+%2B+k))%2F(3+%CE%93(5%2F4)+%CE%93(3%2F2+%2B+k)+%CE%93(7%2F4+%2B+k))+,+k+tends+to+infinity

which approves your value perfectly.

No idea whether such a product converges in general, but you can reduce such a snake-product by a "usual" product with a somewhat more complicated general expression for the factors.

Comment: Wow! $\frac{\sqrt{2} \pi^{3/2}}{\Gamma( \frac{1}{4})^2}$